# Is there a way to disable focusability on an element and all its children?

Tags: xaml, uwp

I am building a UWP app and am wondering if there's a simple and performant way to disable focusability on an element and all its children. `IsTabStop=false` only disables focusability on an individual element, but doesn't get inherited by its children.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reading through the [focus docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.control#controls-and-focus) for Control and it states:

> In order to be focusable, each of these must be true:
>
> - Visibility is Visible
> - IsEnabled is true
> - IsTabStop is true
> - The control must be instantiated with its template loaded

`IsEnabled` disables focus for an entire control (children included). So one approach would be to surround everything in a `<ContentControl>` element (assuming it doesn't already inherit from `Control`) and just set `IsEnabled="False"`.

Answer (score 1):

You could:

1. Loop through the elements and apply `IsTabStop = false` on them (just get the children from the main element and loop on them)
2. Do some binding, binding each control's `IsTabStop` value to the `IsTabStop` value of the main element. Though, depending on how many controls you have, this could get tedious...

Answer (score 1):

Since UWP does not have a focusable property the best thing to do would be to create a GotFocus handler which immediately returns focus to the element that previously had it.